# Upgdade Microsoft.NETCore.UniversalWindowsPlatform from 6.1.7 to 6.1.9 in offline environment

Tags: uwp, windows-10-universal

I'm trying to update Microsoft.NETCore.UniversalWindowsPlatform nuget package from version 6.1.7 to 6.1.9 in a C# project in my **offline environment**.

I get a bunch of errors like that:

> Unable to find package
>   `runtime.win10-arm-aot.Microsoft.NETCore.UniversalWindowsPlatform` with
>   version (>=6.1.9)

**What should I do to install all these dependencies on my offline machine?**

I understand that I could just download all the dependencies graph from the nuget.org but I'd like to know if there is some installer to deploy everything required for `Microsoft.NETCore.UniversalWindowsPlatform 6.1.9`  on my machine.

My environment is following:

- VS 2017 Pro 15.8.5
- Windows 10 Pro 1803/17134.648
- Windows 10 SDKs

  - 10.0.14393.0
  - 10.0.15063.0
  - 10.0.16299.0
  - 10.0.17134.0
  - 10.0.17763.0

Answer (score 0):

Not so sure whether you already know that you can download a offline package from nuget site. For example, in your case it is [here](https://www.nuget.org/api/v2/package/Microsoft.NETCore.UniversalWindowsPlatform/6.1.9).

After you download this package, you can open your Visual Studio->Tools->Nuget package manager->Package Manager Setting->Package Source then click Add to add the source and then click a edit button to change the source to your local location->Update. In this way you will be able to use this to update your environment. Is this what you need?